# Excel add-in with cross platform

Tags: excel, macos, add-in

Can i create a separate Excel Addin (that is not Add-in Express based and for Office 2016 only) with cross platform support wherever Office 2016 runs including Windows, Mac, Office Online and iPad?is there any option?

please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends more on what the add-in is doing, and _how_ you make it - but in either case this question is too broad for SO, try creating one and then ask a question when you run into a reproducible problem with your code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot not create a separate Add-Ins, but you can detect on what platform you run. With this info you can change your app or redirect to another location. For more info see http://simonjaeger.com/where-am-i-detecting-the-office-host-in-office-add-ins/ where it is nicely described how to do this.